# Adding mvc project to asp.net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently in the process of trying to set up my final year project to begin writing but I'm struggling to do so.

Basically, I have an existing project that uses asp.net and need to add a new MVC project where they can run together. The asp.net project will handle the login but with have a simple link to the mvc project. The issue is I can't get the from the asp.net project to the MVC one to work correctly.

I don't want MVC inside the asp.net project but in its own project inside the same solution. I've looked all over for some kind of answer but all I can find is how to add MVC inside an asp.net project.

I can do this with two asp.net projects but am as of yet unable to get an asp.net project working with a new mvc project.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really difficult to understand your exact problem, just on the basis of info provided, apologies for not asking for clarification in comments, as i can't post comments on question requiring a reputation of 50, which at the time of writing i don't have.

@Phil has answered correctly as to how to add a new project to solution, but your comment says that you are not able to reference to MVC project through links in existing project, something like

> href="~/MVC/somecontroller/someaction/someparameters"

If that is something you're after, then the actual logic behind this working is that those two projects have different paths and you'll require to setup virtual directories on same path.

You haven't mention that you're using **ASP.NET 4.5+ MVC 5** or **ASP.NET 5 MVC 6** as procedures are different. For the help of future readers i am posting for both platforms in Visual Studio. Screenshots are from Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, but it's the same across most(if not all) versions after Visual Studio 2012

**ASP.NET 4.5+ MVC 5**

1. Double Click on Properties on existing project which will be root project
2. Click on Tab named "Web"
3. You'll find the Input Box for Project URL
4. Copy the URL
5. Repeat Steps 1-3 for MVC project
6. Paste the Copied URL and append MVC at the end and click on Create Virtual Directory

[image]

**ASP.NET 5 MVC 6**

1. Repeat Steps 1-4 for existing project
2. Open Properties for ASP.NET 5 Project
3. Click on Tab named Debug
4. You'll find the Input Box for App URL under Web Server Settings
5. Paste the copied URL and append MVC to it

[image]

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I've yet to try this but it seems to be what I want to do. 

I need to be able to use a link from the asp 4 project to an MVC 4 project. I believe I've already set up the virutal directories in IIS as I've set up quite a few projects to link together in which you have to do this but they have been asp projects. 

Hopefully this is the correct answer I'm looking for. Thansk again.

Comment: @Abhishek Siddhu , Thanks, now I want to publish the project, but there is no MVC project in publish file

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2013:

1. Show Solution Explorer
2. Right Click on your Solution (DemoWebSol in screen grab)
3. Select Add > New Project ...
4. Proceed with adding the new project as you would normally

[image]

Visual Studio manages different projects are part of the same solution. I'm not sure how other versions of VS do this but it would be a very similar approach.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I've got the two project created. I'm just unable to put a link from the asp.net to the mvc project. As in href=“Mvc/index“ won't work and I can't figure out how to do it from the asp.net project

Comment: You could just use a fully qualified URL like http://localhost/Mvc/index for a very quick fix. Have a look at Abhishek's solution above too, and look into configuring his solution in IIS as well.